# permissions : in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I m working on django rest framework. I m having problems on permissions.
I want to give GET And POST permission to admin user and only POST permission to other users(authentic). So far i have written the following code:

pemisssions.py

```
class UserAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET' or request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user and request.user.is_staff
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()
```

This code is not working as expected. Only admin users are able to GET and POST. And others users are not getting any kind of permission.

Guys help.
Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

```
class UserAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return request.user and request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: This code does not make sense at all. The elif block will never get executed

Comment: okay i forgot to edit

Answer (score 5):

There's a mistake in your conditions. If it's a  GEt request, the first condition always matches, which requires admin permissions.

Here's what you want:

```
class UserAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()    
    elif request.method == 'GET': # no need to check for POST here
            return request.user and request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: does admin have always post permission?

Comment: Yes, if the method is POST,  this always returns True if the user is authenticated, which includes staff/admins.

Comment: there's a problem when I logged in as a normal (authenticated) user (not as admin) in browser I m not able to POST but when i use "Postman Chrome App" then I am able to POST there.

Comment: If you open the dev tools in your browser, you can see the request that is made. Check for differences between the request from Postman vs. the request from the browser.

Comment: The fact that it works in Postman, but not in the browsable API docs means that there's some difference in the way you're sending the request. I suspect it's an issue with authentication. What sort of authentication do you use for the API?

Comment: I m using Token,seession and basic authentication classes.

Comment: So you're probably using basic or token auth in postman, and session auth in the browsable API, right? If so, make sure that the session you're in actually corresponds to an admin user.

Comment: but the admin user is able to POST and GET both and normal users not able to do POST.

Comment: That seems to indicate user.is_authenticated() is returning false for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `elif`, but this part will not be evaluated because if method is `POST` the first condition is always `True`